# Tridion 2011 SP1 - Publication's default workflow only applied to new pages

Tags: workflow, tridion, tridion-2011

I have created a new workflow definition for pages in my publication and have set this as the default on the publication properties.

The problem is that only new pages are triggering the workflow. Existing pages (created before the definition), when edited, do not trigger it.

Has anybody else experienced this and knows of a solution? I'd rather not go through dozens of structure group properties setting the workflow definition.

Comment: I'm surprised you get it for any page. I thought you had to specify the workflow process on the structure group. In publication properties there's only Page and component _template_ process associations, not pages (can't double check on a live server right now).

Comment: Ahh, turns out someone else on the server has been playing around with the structure group properties without telling me. Just checked on my test SG's and it's been set. I was wondering why that was happening, never experienced it with previous versions, figured it was a new 2011 thing :) Thanks

Comment: Great to hear you guys figured it out. Can either of you post the result an answer and mark it as accepted? That way things will be clearer for those who come here later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet one of your colleagues has put this configuration on the structure group(s) and you didn't catch that :) - have a look in there.